# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord field names in JOIN statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am building a query involving a JOIN. This is the first time I've done db stuff with Active Record and I've hit a bit of a snag.

I want to join a table called `companies` to the `users` table so I can get the name of the company etc the user is in. I've done this sort of successfully like so:

```
function get_profile_by_username($username)
{
    $this->db->join('companies', $this->table_name.'.company_id = companies.id');
    $this->db->where('LOWER(username)=', strtolower($username));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();
    return NULL;
}
```

However the issue being that the fields in `companies`, they are `id` and `name` are returned in that object as simply called `name`.

Normally when I would write the raw query I would give aliases to the tables and the result would be something like `u.company_id`, `c.name`. So I'd know `name` had nothing to do with the user but of course is the name of the company. And although not an issue now but potentially in the future, the `id` column obviously can't coexist in the result set, so one gets overwritten!

How can we get this sort of differentiating between the fields that come from certain tables? Or is there a better way of going about table joins and working with joined query data sets/objects?

Edit:

If I was doing it as a raw query I'd do:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, c.name
FROM users AS u
JOIN companies AS c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE u.username = 'foobar';
```

Which is great but if I tried to do that in active record I reckon that's pretty poor practice, if it works at all.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to select some specific columns from table use `db->select()`. You can give alias to tables, add some conditions and etc. Send second parameter `FALSE` to not escape special characters.

```
$this->db->select('u.id, u.username, c.name', false);
$this->db->from('user as u');
$this->db->join('companies as c', 'u.company_id = c.id');
$this->db->where('LOWER(u.username)=', strtolower('foobar'));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I thought I might have to resort to this, but I wasn't confident that I'd be able to select like that. How do I give aliases to the tables like my example then, something like `->get('user AS u')`? Would this be compatible with all activerecord database targets?

Comment: OK that's as I thought. The 'AS' operator is standard SQL right, it sets the alias in all db languages? Or will this only work in certiain db's.

Comment: @deed02392 Afaik, `as` is common in all SQL databases. Also you can give alias withou writing `as`. Like `tablename a`

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->select('ut.nombre as nombreu, ut.apellido,  ru.nombre as nombrer');

$this->db->from('User_table ut');

$this->db->join('Role_usuario ru', 'ut.role_user = ru.Id');

$query = $this->db->get();`
```

`

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to help others learn. Code only answers are considered impolite.

Comment: This answer: 1. is not explained 2. contains non-English 3. makes no attempt to align with the OP's question details 4. represents the lowest-value answer that can be posted.  For these reasons I am dv'ing this answer.