# Codeigniter: Join not working with columns same name and id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanting to be able to join two tables togeather.

How ever because I my **forum table** has `column "name"` and my **forum_categories** `column "name"`

I am not able to display both names.

On my select() if I use like `$this->db->select('f.name, fc.name', false);` it only displays name from forum_categories

`array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(17) "News & Discussion" } }`

> Question how can I get both names to show from both columns and
>   tables.

***Note:*** I only want to be able to use `$result['name']` in my foreach loop.

So the out put I would like it to be

```
General

News & Discussion

Lounge
```

***I have looked at***

[CodeIgniter ActiveRecord field names in JOIN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046249/codeigniter-activerecord-field-names-in-join-statement)

[codeigniter - select from 2 tables with same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193099/codeigniter-select-from-2-tables-with-same-column-name)

***Model***

```
public function get_forums() {
    $this->db->select('f.name, fc.name', false);
    $this->db->from('forum as f');

    // tried $this->db->join('forum_categories as fc', 'fc.forum_id = f.forum_id');

    $this->db->join('forum_categories as fc', 'fc.forum_categories_id = f.forum_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```
<?php

class Forums extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['label'] = '';

        $data['forums'] = array();

        $results = $this->get_forums();

        var_dump($results);

        if (isset($results)) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {

                $data['forums'][] = array(

                    'name' => $result['name'], // Only want to use single variable.

                );
            }
        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('template/forum/list_forum_view', $data);
    }

    public function get_forums() {
        $this->db->select('f.name, fc.name', false);
        $this->db->from('forum as f');
        $this->db->join('forum_categories as fc', 'fc.forum_categories_id = f.forum_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

## update

works fine with code below **but would rather just use one lot of join()**

```
public function get_forums() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('forum');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $f) {
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $f['name']
        );

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('forum_categories');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $fc) {
            $data[] = array(
                'name' => $fc['name']
            );
        }

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: can you just `echo $this->db->last_query();` after the query execution and try executing it directly to phpmyadmin to see what it gives

Comment: @Zeeshan `SELECT f.name, fc.name FROM `forum` as `f` JOIN `forum_categories` as `fc` ON `fc`.`forum_categories_id` = `f`.`forum_id``

Comment: Did you tried executing it in `phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i see in your updated question. What you need is `UNION` and not `JOIN`. You can use [get_compiled_select()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) to build both query before concat with UNION.

```
public function get_forums() {
    $forum = $this->db->select('name')->get_compiled_select('forum');
    $forum_categories = $this->db->select('name')->get_compiled_select('forum_categories');

    $query = $this->db->query($forum.' UNION '.$forum_categories);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try This , It Will Work .

```
    public function get_forums() {
    $this->db->select('f.name as forum_name, fc.name as forum_categories_name', false);
    $this->db->from('forum f');

    // tried $this->db->join('forum_categories fc', 'fc.forum_id = f.forum_id');

    $this->db->join('forum_categories fc', 'fc.forum_categories_id = f.forum_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now shows error on my array on controller Message: Undefined index: name

Comment: If I use have fc.name in select will only show name from forum_categories

Comment: I only want to use the word "name" one word to get both

Comment: @wolfgang1983 you cannot use the same index to get both properties at once. If you are doing stuff with hit, however you could concatenate both columns together into something you want as seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

> AS

keyword, because when you try to print it, that AS keyword give you optional name for your column.

Here i have two table which have same column name "name" so i have changed those with AS keyword.

Ex:

```
$this->db->select('tbl_category.id_category,tbl_category.name AS cat_name,
                     tbl_subject.id_subject,tbl_subject.name AS sub_name');
```

In result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_category] => 9 [cat_name] => OL [id_subject] => 13 [sub_name] => Science )
```

So it is simple solution from the SQL language